# Power Automate remove unresolved users from the List Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We have a requirement to remove thousands of items in a list which corresponds to Unresolved users(users who have left the organization).

how can we remove such items from the list using power automate flow?

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Are these users internal users? So, the main task is to first confirm against the Azure AD 
 that the item creator [Created By] is no longer exist in the tenant, right? You might already know that you can use  [Delete Item] action in the Flow to delete item. Do you need a sample how to use it to delete items form list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove/delete items from SharePoint lists using MS Flow/Power Automate. You can trigger it manually or schedule it. If you have thousands of items in the list, you may not be able to get all of them at one go, but you can execute the flow multiple times as you need it. In addition, you can configure few parameters in the **[Get Items]** settings in the Flow.

I'm assuming accounts for users who left the company are disabled in AD.

[image]

**Pagination, thresholds etc can be updated in the settings**

[image]